# Ignore Condition on 1st Loop

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement

```
if(Z1(m)<Z1(m-1)
   IN=IN+1;
   M1(:,IN)=Vb(:,t);
else
   FCAST=Vb(N,T);
   break;
end
```

I have this condition on my program, but the problem is it cannot work for first iteration because Z1(m)

Did anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Edit your post rather than putting it within a comment where it's impossible for us to read.

Comment: Why on earth would you post code as an image? It's just as easy (if not easier) for you to post it as text and it is *much* easier for us to run as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code you would like in the first iteration in it's own if statement

`IF in == 1 || Z1(m)<Z1(m-1)
 ...`

That might work.

Comment: And set IN = 1 above your loop statement.